# T-SQL Query Problem?

Tags: t-sql

If I exec this query I am getting a output, but not the desired output. I would like to get the output as:

```
FirstName                            LastName


ADT                                  NULL 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(100)

SET @FullName = 'ADT'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@FullName, 1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName) - 1, -1)) AS [FirstName],

SUBSTRING(@FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName) + 1, LEN(@FullName)) AS [LastName]
```

The output will be for this query is:

```
FirstName    LastName

NULL           ADT
------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not the most efficient but meets the requirement.

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(100)

SET @FullName = 'ADT'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@FullName, 0, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName), 0), LEN(@FullName) + 1)) AS [FirstName]
, SUBSTRING(@FullName, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName) + 1, 1), LEN(@FullName) - CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName) + 1) AS [LastName]
```

Here is an updated statement based on the clarified requirement.  The REVERSE string function comes in handy and the LTRIM is due to a leading space issue on the LastName column.

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(100)

SET @FullName = 'ADT SAMPLE DATABASE CASE'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@FullName, 0, ISNULL(NULLIF(LEN(@FullName) + 1 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@FullName)), 0), LEN(@FullName) + 1)) AS [FirstName]
, LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@FullName, NULLIF(LEN(@FullName) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@FullName)), LEN(@FullName)) + 1, LEN(@FullName) - (LEN(@FullName) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@FullName))))) AS [LastName]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but the situation is in my first row the value is single word ADT but in the second row the value is two words ADT SESSION and in the third row the value is ADT SAMPLE DATABASE CASE. so how can we split the 1st word in 1st column and 2nd word in 2nd column and if it comes to 3rd row there are four values and the 1st 3 words should come in 1st cloumn and the last word should goes to 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Add a special-case check if `@FullName` contains a space

or

- Remove the special case by appending a space to the end.

  ```
  declare @fullName varchar(100) = 'ADT'
  select 
      LEFT(@fullName, charindex(' ',@fullName+' ')-1) as FirstName,
      SUBSTRING(@fullname,charindex(' ',@fullName+' ')+1,LEN(@fullname)) as last
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You Mean ADT SAMPLE DATABASE AS FirstName and CASE AS LastName